# diamondback launch problem

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,
I am facing some problem with diamondback setup. I am not able to execute common tasks like launching a node with roslaunch. Following is an example of such problem:

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/navigation_experimental/sbpl_lattice_planner/launch$ roslaunch  ./move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roslaunch", line 2, in <module>
        from ros import roslaunch
    ImportError: No module named ros
```

Earlier i faced no such difficulty. Any idea what could be the reason ??? Does it amounts to reinstallation?

**Update1: Environment variables**

```
 $ echo $ROS_ROOT
    /opt/ros/diamondback/ros
    $ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH 
    /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks
    $ echo $PYTHONPATH 
 /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib
```

rxgraph problem: may be related.

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros$ rxgraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rxgraph", line 34, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('rxgraph')
ImportError: No module named roslib
```

I updated ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH 
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks
```

but error persists.
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30781/diamondback-launch-problem/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-29**:
@prince can you try rosversion ros ? does it work ?

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-31**:
No, ImportError: No module named roslib.stacks

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-31**:
@prince Now that leaves me clueless ! is your ROS PATH set ? ..... still, if I was you I may consider a fresh installation of ROS !

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-31**:
yes ROS PATH is set. I do not what caused the problem. I installed electric as well. electric is working fine but all diamondback package are not part of electric!

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-31**:
yes ROS PATH is set. I do not what caused the problem. I installed electric as well. electric is working fine but all diamondback package are not part of electric!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably just an environment setup problem.

What are `$PYTHONPATH`, `$ROS_ROOT`, and `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` set to?

UPDATE: I don't have a Diamondback installation here to try, but your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` looks suspicious. On my Electric workspace, it is set to: `/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/opt/ros/electric/ros` (preceded by some other stuff).

Try appending "`:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros`" to yours.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-29**:
edited original question.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-31**:
Appending the path did not help. It is still giving same error

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-31**:
Maybe there is something wrong with your $PYTHONPATH, then.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-31**:
What PYTHONPATH  shall point to? In my understanding, this tells where to look for python. What else?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-01**:
Your python path needs to have roslib/src, typical setup scripts say: export PYTHONPATH=${ROS_ROOT}/core/roslib/src:${PYTHONPATH}

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-04-02**:
thanks a lot tfoote. it did work now. I was struggling with this for long time. I even installed diamondback a fresh but this problem persisted.